# Airflow SSH Operator Error: Encountered RSA key, expected OPENSSH key

Tags: airflow

An airflow DAG that runs on Airflow:1.10.10 randomly fails with below traceback:
Airflow is running on docker swarm and same ssh RSA key is used for most of the connections used in Airflow DAG's. Few DAG's randomly fail with below mentioned traceback:

SSH private key is a RSA key  generated using ssh-keygen with default settings.

Traceback:

```
[2020-11-21 18:30:38,821] {taskinstance.py:1145} ERROR - SSH operator error: encountered RSA key, expected OPENSSH key
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 983, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator.py", line 177, in execute
    raise AirflowException("SSH operator error: {0}".format(str(e)))
AirflowException: SSH operator error: encountered RSA key, expected OPENSSH key
[2020-11-21 18:30:38,822] {taskinstance.py:1168} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY
[2020-11-21 18:30:43,763] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-11-21 18:30:43,763] {local_task_job.py:103} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

DAG Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator import SSHOperator
import pendulum
local_timezone = pendulum.timezone("Asia/Calcutta")
default_args = dict(
    depends_on_past=False,
    start_date=datetime(2020,10,20,tzinfo=local_timezone),
    retries=1,
    retry_delay=timedelta(minutes=5),
)

dag = DAG(dag_id='queue_cleanup',
          default_args=default_args,
          schedule_interval='@daily',
          dagrun_timeout=timedelta(seconds=120),
          catchup=False,
          tags=['maintenance'])
print(dag.timezone)

t1_bash = """
sh /home/user/default_jobs/chk_status.sh
"""
t1 = SSHOperator(
    ssh_conn_id='conn_id',
    task_id='ssh_default_queue_cleanup',
    command=t1_bash,
    dag=dag)
```

Connection ID Extra Json:

```
{
   "key_file": "/etc/id_rsa",
   "timeout": "10",
   "compress": "false",
   "no_host_key_check": "true",
   "allow_host_key_change": "false"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. Issue was with the destination node that we were trying to connect using ssh connection id. User account was expired

## chage -l user --> showed that user account is expired.

After activating the user account  everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just to capture this in case someone finds this question.... I received the same error when attempting to connect to an AWS Linux (not ubuntu) instance from Airflow and eventually tracked it down to the fact that the Linux version did not support ssh-rsa. I was particularly confused because I could manually connect using :

```
ssh -i "keyfile.pem" hostname
```

I suspected the problem was a combination of the paramiko version on the Airflow platform, how it was establishing the connection and the target host configuration so....

When I tried to connect from the Airflow (AWS cloud) it failed with the error in the header above. On the target system this command:

```
# journalctl -u sshd | tail -n 100
```

showed this line in the logs

```
userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
```

A little googling and tracing ssh_config.d to its linked destination led me to edit this file on the target system:

```
sudo vi /usr/share/crypto-policies/DEFAULT/opensshserver.txt
```

And add `,ssh-rsa` to the end of the line starting with `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms`

Finally I restarted sshd using:

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd.service
```

Hopefully it saves someone some grief.

I appreciate there may be nicer, better ways to make this work but it sorted the problem.